# Ansible: how to replace hosts at one place

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook in which hosts:all is set at very beginning. In this way all the corresponding roles will assume hosts means all.

But in one of the block of one of the roles, I want to run a command locally, so I set hosts of it as 127.0.0.1, and the playbook fails at this line. I guess it is because Ansible think the hosts should be all. how can I run the command locally in this case?

Here is my code:

```
---
- name: install many things
hosts: all
remote_user: "{{ me }}"
become: true
gather_facts: false

roles:
- service1
- service2
```

roles/service1/tasks/main.yaml:

```
---
- name: Download file
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  command: gsutil cp gs://mybucket/filename.txt /tmp

- name: sudo apt update -y
  apt:
  ...
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: command, hosts

The error appears to be in '/.../roles/service1/tasks/main.yaml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Download file
  ^ here
```

Comment: You can't set `hosts` on a task. The directive is only valid on a play. You may be looking for the [delegate_to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) directive.

Comment: Thanks larsks, I used delegate_to and it works like charms. if you can post the answer I will vote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set hosts on a task. The directive is only valid on a play. You may be looking for the [delegate_to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) directive which allows you to run tasks on a host other than the ones targeted by the current play. For example, your task might be written like this:

```
- name: Download file
  delegate_to: localhost
  command: gsutil cp gs://mybucket/filename.txt /tmp
```

Note that when using `delegate_to`, the task will be run once *for each host in the current play*, and facts will be for the hosts targeted in the play, not for the host on which the task is running.  That is, if you have an inventory like this:

```
---
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
    host2:
```

And a playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - command: echo "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      register: hostname
      delegate_to: localhost

    - debug:
        var: hostname.stdout
```

Then the `command` task will *run* on localhost, but the output will look like this:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [command] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1]
changed: [host2]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "hostname.stdout": "host1"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "hostname.stdout": "host2"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If you only want the task to run a single time regardless of the number of hosts in your play, consider the `run_once` option:

```
- name: Download file
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
  command: gsutil cp gs://mybucket/filename.txt /tmp
```